# Dynamic SQL Error - SQL error code = -104 Token unknown happening on "select * from table". Python Firebird

Tags: python, sql, firebird

I seem to be getting an error while trying to dump all the data from the fdb file.

That was the error. 'BLOB' is the name of the table

```
("Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 15\n- 'BLOB'", -104, 335544569)
```

the code

```
def js(val):
    if type(val) == int:
        return val
    if type(val) == str:
        return val
    if val is None:
        return val
    if type(val) == decimal.Decimal:
        return str(val)
    if type(val) == datetime.datetime:
        return val.isoformat()
    raise Exception(type(val))


con = fdb.connect(dsn='202204.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(
    "SELECT a.RDB$RELATION_NAME FROM RDB$RELATIONS a WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0")


tables = [row[0].strip() for row in cur.fetchall()]

db = {}

for table in tables:
    db[table] = {}
    cur.execute(
        f"select rdb$field_name from rdb$relation_fields where rdb$relation_name='{table}' order by rdb$field_position")

    db[table]['cols'] = [head[0].strip() for head in cur.fetchall()]

    print(db)

    cur.execute(f"select * from '{table}'") # code breaks here

    db[table]['rows'] = [[js(field) for field in row]
                         for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

the expected structure

```
{"BLOB": {"cols": ["GUID", "UPDATE", "DATA"], "rows": []}}
```

Python 3.9
Firebird 2.5

Comment: Which cur.execute is failing?

Comment: #3 cur.execute(f"select * from '{table}'") @jarlh

Comment: What's the `{table}` actual value? Is it `'BLOB'`, `"BLOB"` or `BLOB`?

Comment: `BLOB` the output up until the error is shown in the last code block

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the Python API, but if its cursor object exposes the column names in some way, you can avoid the second query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpolated string `"select * from '{table}'"` will not produce a valid query. Things enclosed in single quotes are string literals, and you cannot select from a string literal. If you intended this as a quoted identifier, you should enclose it in double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`).

That is, right now you produce a statement `select * from 'BLOB'`, which is why the error refers to the unknown token `'BLOB'`, as Firebird expects a (quoted or unquoted) identifier. Change your code to produce  `select * from "BLOB"`.

Also, please be aware that string interpolation like this makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection, although that is less of a problem in this case, as you're selecting from system tables, there are edge cases with table names which contain a double quote (third query), or a single quote (second query). Your second query should use parameters, not string interpolation (this is not possible for the third).